# HAML - error unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

What is wrong with syntax haml? I used 2 spaces.  Display error: **/home/user/myapp/bds/app/views/polls/_voting_form.html.haml:14: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input**

```
= form_tag votes_path, method: :post, remote: true, id: 'voting_form'
  = hidden_field_tag 'poll[id]', @poll.id

  = render partial: 'polls/poll_item', collection: @poll.poll_items, as: :item  

  %p 
    %b Итого голосов: = @poll.votes_count

  - if current_user.voted_for?(@poll)
    %p Вы уже голосовали!
  - else
    = submit_tag 'Голосовать', class: 'btn-bg'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two errors:

- you are missing the `do` on the `form_tag` line.
- the second error is not blocking, but for the `votes_count`: either use string interpolation, or write on multiple lines (now it would just print it as a string)

So easiest solution imho would be to write

```
%b Итого голосов: #{@poll.votes_count}
```

Comment: You can also do: `%b= "Итого голосов: #{@poll.votes_count}"`

Comment: Of course, that is just standard assigning a string (which happens to be interpolated), but haml allows an even [shorter form](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_interpolation_). Of course as usual, it is a matter of taste :)

Comment: I prefer the form I did, because the shorter form says "it might compile to..."

Comment: It says "might compile to .." because (of course!) they give an example what the contents of the variable is (it depends on the value of the contained variables what it _might compile to_). It also says (in the top two lines) "is the same as" ...

Comment: Okay, I took that as "this may or may not compile at all". Thanks! I learned something new!

Answer (score 2):

Here are two errors:

```
= form_tag votes_path, method: :post, remote: true, id: 'voting_form' # <= missing do
  ....
  %p 
    %b Итого голосов: = @poll.votes_count # <= no valid haml
```

should be

```
= form_tag votes_path, method: :post, remote: true, id: 'voting_form' do
  ....
  %p 
    %b 
      Итого голосов:
      = " #{@poll.votes_count}"
```

You may not prepend normal text to a ruby snippet which requires `=`. I don't think that there is a compiler that could interprete this.
so:

```
%b= @poll.votes_count # this works
%b Votes count: = @poll.votes_count # this does not
```

Therefore:

```
%b 
  Итого голосов:
  = " #{@poll.votes_count}"
```

or

```
%b= "Итого голосов: #{@poll.votes_count}"
```

is the way to go.

Comment: thank you. i changed, like you, but again error: **  home/user/myapp/bds/app/views/polls/_voting_form.html.haml:16: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input **

Comment: Check the other answer, you were also missing `do` on your `= form_tag`. I'll update the answer